# A select in rails query does not return an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the rails 3 query in the app:

```
Order.where('id IN (?)',ContractItem.where(contract_id: @contract.id).select('contract_item_id'))
```

Here is the only record in contract_item table:

[image]

As shown in the record, the `@contract.id` is equal to 1 and we expect `ContractItem.where(contract_id: @contract.id).select('contract_item_id')` returns array [2].
So `Order.where('id IN (?)',ContractItem.where(contract_id: @contract.id).select('contract_item_id'))`should return `order#2`. However what we have got is nothing. We figure an empty array must be returned instead. Is there something wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting back an array, but it's an array of ContractItem objects with a single column, not an array of numbers.

Try instead...

```
Order.where('id IN (?)',ContractItem.where(contract_id: @contract.id).pluck(:contract_item_id))
```

Comment: Or use `pluck` method, `ContractItem.where(contract_id: @contract.id).pluck(:contract_item_id)`

Comment: Yes, @Iceman good point!  Don't need to return the whole record. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Here is an article about pluck and select. http://rubyinrails.com/2014/06/rails-pluck-vs-select-map-collect/